# pd.read_hdf got error when file name or path contain Chinese characters

Tags: pandas

I found that `pd.to_hdf` and `pd.read_hdf` will got error when the file name or path contain Chinese characters. For example:

`df = pd.read_hdf(r'C:\Users\xxyao\research\卡尔曼滤波\data\IC.h5', 'data')`

will got error:

> End of HDF5 error back trace
>   Unable to open/create file 'C:\Users\xxyao\research\卡尔曼滤波\data\IC.h5'

but `df = pd.read_hdf(r'C:\Users\xxyao\research\CalmanFilter\data\IC.h5', 'data')`will work.

Comment: Have you tried to give unicode string instead of raw string, ie : call .decode('UTF8') on your string

Comment: You mean   `df = pd.read_hdf(r'C:\Users\xxyao\research\卡尔曼滤波\data\IC.h5'.encode('UTF8'), 'data')`?   It got error`NotImplementedError: Support for generic buffers has not been implemented.`. But if I use `decode` instead of `encode()`. It got error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: It looks like you are in python3 and str are already unicode objects that doesn't need to be decoded. In this case, my previous comment cannot help you, sorry